# How to get rows with the maximum timestamp for each uniqueId

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table defined as follows:

```
mysql> select * from rules;
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | uniqueId | name  | json         | definition    | createdAt           |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v1 | Rule 1 Def v1 | 2016-05-13 09:10:44 |
|  2 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v1 | Rule 2 Def v1 | 2016-05-13 09:12:04 |
|  3 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 1 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:14:04 |
|  4 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v3 | Rule 1 Def v3 | 2016-05-13 09:14:15 |
|  5 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v4 | Rule 1 Def v4 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  6 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 2 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:14:31 |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I know the SQL query I want to run to get the required rows:

```
mysql> select * from rules where createdAt in (select max(createdAt) from rules group by uniqueId);
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | uniqueId | name  | json         | definition    | createdAt           |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  5 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v4 | Rule 1 Def v4 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  6 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 2 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:14:31 |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I tried to get the Slick query but I'm getting stuck. So far I can build the subquery as follows:

```
val latestVersionOfRules = Rules.groupBy(p => p.uniqueId).map{ case(uniqueId, group) => (uniqueId, group.map(_.createdAt).max) }
```

However, I don't then have access to the createdAt values in order to join with the outer table.

I'm not sure how to build the complete query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with: Your query as-is doesn't do quite what you want it to, since it's only selecting based on the timestamp in your query. If you have multiple rows with a max timestamp, you'll select all of them. For example, if you have:

```
mysql> select * from rules;
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | uniqueId | name  | json         | definition    | createdAt           |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v1 | Rule 1 Def v1 | 2016-05-13 09:10:44 |
|  2 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v1 | Rule 2 Def v1 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  3 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 1 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:14:04 |
|  4 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v3 | Rule 1 Def v3 | 2016-05-13 09:14:15 |
|  5 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v4 | Rule 1 Def v4 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  6 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 2 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:15:31 |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Note that the timestamp on row 2 equals the max timestamp of ABC.

You'll return:

```
mysql> select * from rules where createdAt in (select max(createdAt) from rules group by uniqueId);
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | uniqueId | name  | json         | definition    | createdAt           |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  2 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v1 | Rule 2 Def v1 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  5 | ABC      | Rule1 | Json Repr v4 | Rule 1 Def v4 | 2016-05-13 09:14:22 |
|  6 | DEF      | Rule2 | Json Repr v2 | Rule 2 Def v2 | 2016-05-13 09:15:31 |
+----+----------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Not what you want! In SQL, you'd join on a subselect. This can be done in Slick:

```
// Create the query getting you the unique ID and max.
val latestVersionOfRules = Rules.groupBy(p => p.uniqueId).map {
  case(uniqueId, group) => (uniqueId, group.map(_.createdAt).max)
}

// Join your table to the query. This is a DBIO of whatever your Rules
// result type is.
val results = Rules.join(latestVersionOfRules).on {
  case (rulesRow, groupRow) =>
    rulesRow.uniqueId === groupRow._1 &&
      rulesRow.createdAt === groupRow._2
}.map {
  case (rulesRow, _) => rulesRow
}.result
```

One final thing to note: This will *still* return multiple rows per `uniqueId` if multiple rows have the same max timestamp.

Comment: The query I posted will not bring back more than one row per uniqueId. In your example, in the subquery for the DEF group the row with id 6 would have been chosen not the row with id 2. With regards to the last query, the result type is not of List[Seq[Rule]]. This is what I want but am not sure how to get it. Any ideas on that. The type of the `results` as per your code is `JdbcProfile.this.StreamingDriverAction[List[(Rule, (String, Option[LocalDateTime]))], (Rule, (String, Option[LocalDateTime])), Read]`.

Comment: I added the missing `map` call to my answer so the query now returns the correct row type. As for the SQL, the subquery is correct: It will return two rows. The problem is that you're then joining *only* on `createdAt`, which means *all* rows that match *any* `max(createdAt)` will be returned.